# boost::geometry and std namespace conflict with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, namespaces, boost-geometry

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and wizard created Win32 Console Application project. This code:

```
    #include <boost/geometry.hpp>
    #include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost::geometry;

    int main()
    {
        model::d2::point_xy<int> p1(1, 1), p2(2, 2);
        cout << "Distance p1-p2 is: " << distance(p1, p2) << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

produces a long template barf starting with:

```
error C2039: 'iterator_category' : is not a member of 'boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<int,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>'
```

The same code runs fine with gcc and clang. Do I have to change my project settings to make it compile?

**EDIT**

This code works fine with Visual Studio 2015 CTP, so the problem is a deficiency of overload resolution in VS2013 as [Marc Glisse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1918193/marc-glisse) pointed out.

`using namespace std` is not a root of the problem here as [juanchopanza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661519/juanchopanza) claims. Considering it a bad practice is somewhat arbitrary, as there are many arguments to the contrary (see discussion at [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)). In this specific case, one can argue that `using namespace boost::geometry` is a bad practice, not `using namespace std`.

The quest of some editors to remove all redundancy from stackoverflow questions will make search more difficult, due to chicken and egg paradox: one would have to know an answer to the question before embarking on a successful search. Ultimately you could reduce the entirety of stackoverflow to 42, but utility would suffer.

Comment: Which line is causing the problem?

Comment: I am adding "long template barf" to my lexicon.  Thank you.

Comment: @JamesAdkison `cout << "Distance p1-p2 is: " << distance(p1, p2) << endl` is the line with error message.

Comment: @PaulJurczak Posts marked as duplicate are not removed, they are kept to make it easier to find the answer in the other post. http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Comment: This is not a deficiency in VS, it was only specified this way in C++14 (or later, I don't remember). Multiplying the `using namespace` is still a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) function computes the distance between two iterators.

Try removing the `using namespace std` or properly qualify the boost `distance` function.

### Edit

> The question remains, why gcc and clang didn't complain?

As [@MarcGlisse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1918193/marc-glisse) points out the reason for this may boil down to the level of sophistication employed by the C++ library implementation:

> Recent versions of libstdc++ and libc++ use sfinae
>
> Old versions of Visual Studio don't do that yet

This is a very plausible explanation as to why it works for some compilers and not others, as SFINAE is a mechanism to remove functions from the set of possible functions the compiler will consider. For more information about SFINAE ([cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) and [WIKIPEDIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error))

Comment: No, still the same problem.

Comment: Using `boost::geometry::distance` solves the problem, thank you. The question remains, why gcc and clang didn't complain? Shouldn't the template resolution continue until all possible options are exhausted?

Comment: @PaulJurczak I'm not sure why it works for those compilers but not Visual Studio 2013. It seems that for Visual Studio it doesn't keep looking because it found the match it wants, it's just the chosen match doesn't compile (perhaps the headers you're including on those platforms never include `<iterator>`?).

Comment: Recent versions of libstdc++ and libc++ use sfinae to constrain the arguments of std::distance, so unsuitable arguments mean this overload is ignored. Old versions of Visual Studio don't do that yet and have a hard error.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thank you, that sounds like a very plausible reason. I updated my answer based on your feedback.

Comment: @MarcGlisse You are right. The same code works fine with Visual Studio 2015 CTP.